# Why does XInput recognise DualSense controller over USB but not Bluetooth?

Tags: gamepad, xinput

I can connect a Sony DualSense (PS5) controller to Windows via USB or Bluetooth.

The HTML5 Gamepad API recognises the DualSense whether I connect over USB and Bluetooth work with https://gamepad-tester.com/

However with XInput the DualSense only works over USB. Over Bluetooth, nothing happens. https://thatsmytrunks.itch.io/xinput-controller-tester

Why is that? And can it be fixed? I tested an Xbox controller with XInput, and it works over either USB or Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2):

DualSense isn't recognized through XInput because it's not an XInput compatible game controller. XInput is a legacy interface for Xbox 360 and Xbox One controllers and isn't compatible with HID gamepads.

You can run software like [DS4Windows](https://ryochan7.github.io/ds4windows-site/) that will create a virtual XInput device that mirrors the inputs from a compatible controller. DS4Windows works with DualShock4, DualSense, Switch Pro Controller, and Switch Joy-Cons.

Applications that don't need compatibility with versions of Windows earlier than Windows 10 should use the [Windows.Gaming.Input API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input) which has built-in support for HID gamepads (including DualSense).

DualSense works in Chrome because Chrome uses the Windows HID API to read inputs from HID gamepads like DualSense.

Comment: Thanks. Why did Dualsense work with XInput over USB at all? Is the USB connection different to the Bluetooth?

Comment: Also, do you know of any Windows.Gaming.Input test app?